# How can I prune dependencies from a py_binary runfiles

Tags: python, bazel

I'd like to build an executable python zip file by using a py_binary rule and building with "--build_python_zip".

However, the py_binary rule pulls in a bunch of dependencies (e.g. TensorFlow) which I want to exclude from the zip file because they will be provided by the system where it runs.

Is there an existing way to do this or do I need to define a custom build rule?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Bazel pulls in Tensorflow dependency with builtin py_binary rules.

1. Is it possible that you pull it in yourself (e.g. py_binary depends on 'foo' and 'foo' depends on Tensorflow)?
2. If not, are you sure you use builtin Bazel rules (i.e. isn't some .bzl file defining a custom py_binary implementation in Skylark)?
3. If not, can you share the BUILD file? This will be interesting :)